# Send complex data to C# with jQuery

Tags: c#, ajax, api, query-string

I have a JavaScript object like so that I want to send to C# (question right at the bottom)

```
var data = {
    mykey1: "somevalue",
    mykey2: "somevalue2",
    addProducts: [
        {
            id: 1,
            quantity: 3,
            variation: 54
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            quantity: 5,
            variation: 23
        }
    ]
}
```

It is to add either a single product or multiple products to a users basket. I want to send an array of objects back..

I can access this in Javascript by using

```
data.addProducts[1].id
```

using the below...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/myurl",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function( response ){
        // Data returned as JSON
    }
});
```

it is sending the data like this (URLdecoded for your reading pleasure)

```
?mykey1=somevalue&mykey2=somevalue2&addProducts[0][id]=1&addProducts[0][quantity]=3&addProducts[0][variation]=54&addProducts[0][id]=2&addProducts[0][quantity]=5&addProducts[0][variation]=23
```

My question is... without using `JSON.stringify` on the data, which will just send it as a full object in the url `/ajax/myurl/{mykey1:1 ...}`

How can I read this information back in from C#? jQuery is just encoding it as the standard way, should I be doing anything else to this, and is there a built in way to grab this data in C#?

Comment: What technologies are you using on the C# side? For example, ASP.NET MVC would be able to deserialize this into object form 100% automatically once you set up the necessary classes.

Comment: Is using of GET method a strict requirement?

Comment: GET is not a strict method, but I am not updating or creating anything with this API call POST / PUT.

Comment: Yes we are using MVC 3.5 server size

Comment: @Aaron: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to fix this in WebForms way aswell... We have mixed sites. p.s. thanks @Jon we will take a look at the link

Answer (score 0):

```js
var strValue = $(getStringValue);
var intValue = $(getIntValue)
$.ajax({
type: \"post\",
url: \"default.aspx/getData\",
data: \"{\'postedAjaxStringValue\"\': \'\" + encodeURIComponent(strValue) + \"\', postedAjaxIntValue: \" + encodeURIComponent(intValue ) + \"}\",
contentType: \"application/json; charset=utf-8\",
dataType: \"json\",
success: OnSuccess,
failure: function (response) {
error: function (response) {
});
```

//ON C# KodeBehind..

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string getData(string postedAjaxStringValue, int postedAjaxIntValue){}
```